# Do family member's escape the Calamity if the student dies?

Tags: another

When the Calamity begin, relatives to a student in class 3-3 are also at risk of dying due to the Calamity.

I am wondering, if a student died as a result of the Calamity would their relatives be spared?

Comment: Most probably there will not be a definitive answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not sure but, by logic, when a student dies, he is no more a student in class 3-3, so their relatives are safe.

In fact, in the anime, nothing happens to any relative of a dead student.

Comment: Takabayashi's grandparents were the inkeepers and died two months after him

Answer (score 1):

TL.DR: they can and did die!

The rules for someone die of the calamity are:

- Be a student, teacher or up to second degree relative of a 3-3 class' student.
- Be alive. (The calamity would not kill the dead member of the class)
- Be inside the city limits. Junta died at the beach, but he had already fatal injuries priorvto leaving the city.

So, if a student transfers schools or leaves the city for good, the link to the class ends and the  person's family would be safe.

Also, Koichi's father, being in another country, is totally safe.

Being dead is no protection to a student's family. *Takabayashi dies of heart attack in June* (DN reference not intended... >.>), but his grandparents die as part of the calamity in August.

Being a relative of the ignored student is no protection, as Mei sister shows.